# Continuous Deployment on App Engine with Gitlab CI Fail with no error

Tags: git, google-app-engine, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci

I'm currently working on the continuous deployment of a web application (server Python, front Node.js) to Google App Engine. When the app is pushed on develop or master, the CI server makes four stages: install dependencies, build, test, deploy. There's no error during these steps. When pushing on develop, it should upload on GAE on the dev version without migrating traffic. When pushing on master, it should upload on GAE on the prod version and auto-migrate traffic.

I wrote something very similar to the Google documentation for Continuous Deployment on GAE with TravisCI and CircleCI, but I can see strange behaviour concerning the files that are served on App Engine.

The strange behaviour I'm talking about is that when deploying to GAE with the command:

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml --no-promote -v dev
```

I can see the dev version updated on GAE, and that the files served are not the same, but sometimes it corresponds to the good files, sometimes it corresponds to a (very) old commit, not always the same, that has been pushed weeks ago. Anyway, the output of the deploy command (with debug level) say that sometimes some static files are "skipped", sometimes not. I know that when deploying to an already existing version, App Engine recognize what files are modified and should be uploaded. Unfortunately, when I modify a single character for example, the file is not always considered as modified and is not uploaded.

When trying to find the problem, I saw that files are uploaded on a bucket in Google Cloud Storage and are renamed with the sha1sum. 
On the CI server, the output of the "deploy" stage concerning a static file say that it is well upload, and when I look the uploaded file in the bucket, it is the good version. For my mine, no problem on the GitLab side.

```
DEBUG: Uploading [/builds/apps/ex-app-name/static/main.js] to [2d660f94a0ec70a64892a1539938bf404d4d45f9]
INFO: Uploading [/builds/apps/ex-app-name/static/main.js] to [2d660f94a0ec70a64892a1539938bf404d4d45f9]
```

Recently, I find out that all the files of the previous versions are in the same bucket. A conflict between these files could eventually explain all the encountered problems and the famous strange behaviour. For example, when I give an empty bucket to the command deploy (with --bucket option), it seems that first deployment succeed, but not the second one and the others...

Here is the content of my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - install
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

variables:
  CI_PROJECT_ID: ex-ci-project-id
  PROJECT_ID: ex-project-id
  APP_NAME: ex-app-name

image: eu.gcr.io/$CI_PROJECT_ID/$APP_NAME:latest

install_dependencies:
  stage: install
  script:
    - pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib
    - cd client
    - npm install
  cache:
      key: "$CI_PIPELINE_ID/$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
      paths:
        - client/node_modules
        - lib

build_app:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd client
    - npm run build
  cache:
      key: "$CI_PIPELINE_ID/$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
      paths:
        - client/node_modules
        - static
        - lib

test_app:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd client
    - npm test
  cache:
      key: "$CI_PIPELINE_ID/$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
      paths:
        - client/node_modules
        - static
        - lib

deploy_app_dev:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - /google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud app deploy app.yaml --verbosity=debug --no-promote -v dev
  environment: development
  only:
    - develop
  cache:
      key: "$CI_PIPELINE_ID/$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
      paths:
        - static
        - lib

deploy_app_prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - /google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud app deploy app.yaml --verbosity=debug --promote -v prod
  environment: production
  only:
    - master
  cache:
      key: "$CI_PIPELINE_ID/$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
      paths:
        - static
        - lib
```

My questions are:

- is it possible to make continuous deployment on App Engine with only two versions dev and prod ? Or should I create a new version for each commit ?
- is the google storage behaviour considered as normal ? I thought the old files should be removed from the bucket but that's not the case.

I'm pretty sure that GitLab CI send the good files to App Engine, so I don't think the problem is here.
All propositions/suggestions are welcome.

Thank you in advance !

Loïc